# Use Flask XML-RPC with HTTPAuth?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, xml-rpc, http-authentication

I am using the Flask [XML-RPC extension](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-XML-RPC/) and everything is working well. Now I want to protect the XML-RPC endpoint with a basic HTTP authentication using Flask [HTTPAuth extension](https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.org).

This extension is usually used with routes, but the XML-RPC endpoint is not defined as a route:

```
handler = XMLRPCHandler('xmlrpc')
handler.connect(app, '/xml-rpc')

def hello_word():
    return "Hello"

handler.register_function(hello_world)
```

How can I use HTTP authentication with Flask-XML-RPC so that any caller of `/xml-rpc` has to authenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to *subclass* the `XMLRPCHandler()` class; each call through `/xml-rpc` is handled by the [`XMLRPCHandler.handle_request()` method](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-XML-RPC/#flaskext.xmlrpc.XMLRPCHandler.handle_request), you can decorate that to handle authentication:

```
class HTTPAuthXMLRPCHandler(XMLRPCHandler):
    @auth.login_required
    def handle_request(self):
        return XMLRPCHandler.handle_request(self)

handler = HTTPAuthXMLRPCHandler('xmlrpc')
handler.connect(app, '/xml-rpc')
```

Comment: For line 4, I get a `TypeError: unbound method handle_request() must be called with XMLRPCHandler instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

Comment: OK while it is authenticating now, I am getting a `ValueError: View function did not return a response` error for the `/xml-rpc` (POST) path...

Comment: It works now. handle_request has to return the handler request. Submitted an edit.

Comment: @boadescriptor: see, that's why I shouldn't answer before drinking my morning cup of caffeine.